# Why is Spark able to count faster on a joined table?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, join, count

So I'm assuming that there's some configuration issue here or something of the sort. This behaviour is very strange for performance.

I have a table in Hive which contains 200M records (call it default.tbl). It's compressed using ORC format and physically constitutes 50 files ranging between 100-200MB (7.6GB total).

I launch spark-shell with the following runtime configuration:

```
spark-shell --master yarn --executor-memory 14G --executor-cores 5 --num-executors 16
```

It launches 16 executors distributed between 6 data nodes and allocates 9.8GB of memory to each of them.

I launch the following DAG:

```
val a = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM TBL")
a.count()
```

Which submits a ShuffleMapStage with 50 tasks and takes approximate 95s to complete.

However, when I launch this DAG:

```
val a = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM TBL")
val b = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM TBL")
val c = a.join(b, "id")
c.count()
```

It submits two ShuffleMapStages, each with 50 tasks, which complete in about 35s (in parallel). Then it submits a ShuffleMapStage with 200 tasks which completes in about 13s, at which point the job finishes having taken only 48s.

How is it possible that Spark is able to join a table with itself and count the results faster than simply counting the records in the table? I've explored reparitioning the DataFrames but was not able to improve performance of counting.